# Login to webpage with python requests library, status code 200, failing to parse and unauthorized pages still unauthorized

Tags: python, python-3.x, beautifulsoup, python-requests, html-parsing

I'm attempting to build my first web scraper, which is aiming to scrape some data tables from a website and use them to populate pandas dataframes. The website requires a login. The webiste is called **spotrac.com**.

I'm running into a couple of issues. The first is that when I run the beautifulsoup post method I get the following error: "InvalidURL: Failed to parse: <Response [200]>". This error occurs when I run the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests, lxml.html
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

with requests.session() as s:    
    login = s.get('http://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/')
    form = {'redirect' : '',
            'email' : 'my_email@gmail.com',
            'password' : 'my_password',
            }    

    p = s.post(login, data=form)

    r1 = s.get('http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/quarterback/')
    soup1 = BeautifulSoup(r1.content,'lxml')
    table1 = soup1.find_all('table')[0]
    df1 = pd.read_html(str(table1))
    
    r2 = s.get('http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2018/base/quarterback/')
    soup2 = BeautifulSoup(r2.content,'lxml')
    table2 = soup2.find_all('table')[0]
    df2 = pd.read_html(str(table2))
    
    print(r1.status_code) # 200
    print(r2.status_code) # 200
```

To allow my code to continue running, I put the post line in a try block, as follows:

```
with requests.session() as s:    
    try:
        p = s.post(login, data=form)
    except:
        pass
```

This does allow my code to continue running, and when I print out the status code, it shows 200. I believe this confirms that I am logged in?

The issue I run into after this is that when I go to a webpage that is unauthorized, the datatables aren't populating as if I am signed in. In my code, you'll see r1 and r2. When I go through the process of getting the datatable from r1, I have no issue. I believe that is because it is **publicly available**. When I try the same process for r2, I get the following error: "IndexError: list index out of range". This error occurs because the webpage does not load the data table, as the data table is only available to premium customers who have logged in. I know this is the case, because if you go to the r1 webpage (http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2019/base/quarterback/), you'll see a datatable without logging in. If you attempt to go to the r2 webpage (http://www.spotrac.com/nfl/rankings/2018/base/quarterback/), you will **not** see a datatable. Instead, you get redirected to a login page.

Any help you can provide would be greatly appreciated! I really don't know how to proceed at this point.

Thank you,
David

Comment: all login systems use Cookies to keep you logged and you may have to use `requests.Session()` to keep cookies and use with next requests.

Comment: always put full error message (starting at word "Traceback") in question (not comment) as text (not screenshot). There are other useful information.

Comment: full error message should show you in which line of code you have probleme and then you should use `print()`, `print(type(...))` to see what you have variables - probably you have wrong values (different values then you expect). It is called "print debuging"

Comment: code `except: pass` is the worst idea. You can get error but you will don't know it and you will don't know why code doesn't run as you are expecting. And you will don't know what to change to fix it. You should do at least `execp Exceptions as ex: print(ex)`. Using `except: pass` you only hide problem but you don't fix it.

Comment: code `200` confirms only that server recognized requested `URL` and it sends respone (usually with HTML), nothing more. it doesn't confirm that you are logged in. You have to get HTML and check if there is some text/element which you can see only when you are logged in.

Comment: BTW: sometimes it is good to GET login page before POST data because this way you can get some cookies which it may need in POST. And sometimes servers may check headers - mostly `User-Agent` - but `reuqests` send something like `Python/3.7` instead of `Mozilla/5.0` or similar

Comment: BTW: I see mistakes in code - you use `s.get() before `with requests.session() as s:` and you use `post(login,... )` but it is `login = s.get()` - it makes no sense.

Comment: I test your code and it doesn't get table even for first url - I had to use `s.headers.update({'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0'})` to get it. All your code is big mess and you only waste our time. BTW: to get table you can do `df = pd.read_html(r.content)` without `Beautifulsoup`

Comment: Thank  you, @furas. I appreciate you taking a look. Apologies for the mess, but I did eventually figure this out by digging further into the error message as you suggested.

Answer (score 1):

This was actually a very silly mistake. The issue is that I was passing the following "login" variable to the post method, rather than the login url:

```
login = s.get('http://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/')
p = s.post(login, data=form)
```

I still wanted to run the get method, so I just assigned the url to a separate variable. Simple fix:

```
login = 'http://www.spotrac.com/signin/submit/'
r = s.get(login)
p = s.post(login, data=form)
```